# Record what I'm doing in Firefox, Chrome or IE8/9?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, dom, google-chrome

Is there a way in any of the three major Windows Browsers (Firefox 3.6, Chrome, Internet Explorer 8 and soon 9) and ideally for Safari on Mac to 'record' my interactions with the Website?

By that I mean recording something like

- Clicked Button 'btnSubmit'
- Entered 'bla' in input 'txtSubject'

DOM Interactions that is. I'm guessing I could have a global mousedown/keydown handler, but I want it to work on any website.

I need to get a 'textual' representation - can be anything, but I need to send it to a webservice and process it there, so I need some raw data to work with.

I only need it for one (Windows) Browser, but some pointers for each one would be appreciated.

Bonus Points if I can start/stop recording from another process (running on the same PC in the same session as the user) that communicates with my extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can use iMacros.